# Angular js seperation to different modules in different js files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, angularjs-directive

I created an angular web application that enables drag and drop elements.

I finish building it, but i have one big module. The module is placed in one js file with thousand of code lines.

I would like to know how can i separate my big modules to several modules in several js files that communicate with each other.

May someone provide me simple example how can i do it?

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to know how can i separate my big modules to several modules in several js files that communicate with each other.

Sure you can use several modules and bind them like in following example:

```
var firstModule = angular.module('firstModule', []);
var secondModule = angular.module('secondModule', ['firstModule']);
```

Now all services/directives created in `firstModule` are visible in `secondModule`.

But before you create two modules you should ask yourself:

**1. two modules**

Multiple modules as I know is good way if your project has different sections with different dependencies.

For example one module uses `ui.bootstrap` when other is empty, like:

```
var firstModule = angular.module('firstModule', []);
var secondModule = angular.module('secondModule', ['ui.bootstrap','firstModule']);
```

**2. two controllers**

The multiple controller approach is good to split business logic and make code clearer

**3. one controller in two js files**

You would want to implement this way (since we don't know your project goals)

For example:

**controllers.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('someCtrl', function($scope) {

     // call other js file:
     otherFile($scope);

    /*....*/
});
app.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

**someotherfile.js**

```
var otherFile = function($scope) {
/*...*/
});
```

Comment: I think that in my case i need to split one controller to several js files. I tried what you suggested , but i got an error that $scope is not defined. I moved one function from one.js to two.js.

Comment: Try to add ` app.$inject = ['$scope'];` under defined controller

Comment: "i need to split one controller to several js files" Please no! Extract logic into multiple services instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should follow [the official Angular tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) to learn about the dependency injection and various types of components available in AngularJS. That will give you a good overview of how to split your code base into several layers.

A small set of best practices:

- Services - are used to keep the business logic and communication with APIs/other systems in one place
- Directives - are used to keep the code which modifies the DOM elements directly
- Controllers - a bridge between the view (HTML - DOM) and services
- Modules - larger sets of features can be encapsulated in module, which helps to reuse larger components

Have a look [this site](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide) with details about proper scaffolding in AngularJs.

Comment: Your second link does not work anymore