# Not able to Access Services on Two Controller AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

I Need to use same data on Two different Controller, One is page while other is Modal Popup. I created service which will perform $http.get to pull data. However, when I apply service to Modal Popup, it stops loading and even data is not load anywhere.

My Service

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  angular.module('sspUiApp.services')
    .service('AdUnitService', ['$http', '$rootScope', 'API_URL', function($http, $scope, API_URL) {
      var data = $http.get('data/selectAdUnits.json');

      return {
        getAdFormats: function() {
          console.log("inside function");
          return data;
        },
        setAdFormats: function(value) {
        }
      }
    }]);
})();
```

My Both Controller with Services added.

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('sspUiApp.controllers')
    .controller('AdUnitFormatCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'AdUnitService', function ($scope, $state, AdUnitService) {
        $scope.details = AdUnitService.getAdFormats();
    }])

    .controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ['AdUnitService', function ($scope, $uibModal, AdUnitService) {
      $scope.open = function (size) {
        // $scope.details = AdUnitService.getAdFormats();
        $scope.$modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          scope: $scope,
          templateUrl: 'views/select_ad_format.html',
          size: size,
        });
      };
      $scope.cancel = function () {
        $scope.$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
      };

      $scope.details = AdUnitService.getAdFormats();
      alert($scope.details);
    }])
})();
```

And HTML

```
<div id="selectAdFormats" ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ad-format-section">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 selectedAdFormatData" ng-repeat="frmt in details.adformat">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
                <img ng-src="../images/{{ frmt.ad_image }}" ng-if="frmt.ad_image"/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  text-center">
                <span class="formatName">{{ frmt.name }}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  text-center">
                <span class="resSize">{{ frmt.size }}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't believe you are using the modal instantiation as intended.  By having the modal open itself, you are forced to have its scope available prematurely.  Also, it would seem you would love the ability to use the `resolve` syntax to pass in dependencies instead of passing in the entire `$scope`.  I think it could help in this situation and pass in the variables needed to the modal from the calling controller rather than sharing data via a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angular.module('sspUiApp.services')
angular.module('sspUiApp.controllers')
```

Your service is in a different module, that's why you can't get to it, if you declare it into the same module it should work

Option 2:

Include your second module `sspUiApp.services` in your decleration of `sspUiApp.controllers`

for more info: [Angular js seperation to different modules in different js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836561/angular-js-seperation-to-different-modules-in-different-js-files)

---

Update:

```
var data = $http.get('data/selectAdUnits.json');

return {
    getAdFormats: function() {
      console.log("inside function");
      return data;
    },
    setAdFormats: function(value) {}
}
```

The problem is is that data is asynchronious and you don't treat it like so:

```
$scope.details = AdUnitService.getAdFormats();
alert($scope.details);
```

You try to alert a promise, instead of waiting for it to resolve and alerting the result, if you change it into the following it should work:

```
AdUnitService.getAdFormats().then(function(details) {
    alert(details);     
});
```

This way angular will wait on the result before executing the code.

More info about Angular promises here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Dependency for services and controller is already mentioned in app.js file. I'm getting Object Object data but it's not viewed on page.